# Creating a list of Domino

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get a sorted list of `Domino` with a list of `Domino`

My code currently looks like:

```
listdomino(_,[],[],[]).    
listdomino([I,J],M,Start,Fin):-
    (( member([J,K],M),
       delete(M,[J,K],M2),
       append([[J,K]],Fin1,Fin),
       listdomino([I,K],M2,Start,Fin1)
     )
   ;
    ( member([K,I],M),
      delete(M,[K,I],M2),
      append(Start1,[[K,I]],Start),
      listdomino([K,J],M2,Start1,Fin)
    )
   ).

listdominoSorted(X,M,Out):-
    append(Start,[X],K),
    append(K,Fin,Out),
    listdomino(X,M,Start,Fin).
```

Actual outcome:

```
?- listdominoSorted([1,2],[[2,1],[2,2]],L).
L = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]] ;
L = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]] ;
L = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]] ;
L = [[2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]] ;
```

The program returns `[[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]` twice
and doesn't exit after that.

Desired outcome:

```
?- listdominoSorted([1,2],[[2,1],[2,2]],L).
L = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]] ;
L = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]] ;
L = [[2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]] ;
false
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog domino game](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453366/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog Domino Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380238/1243762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code for a minute or two but after seeing the use of [delete/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=delete/3) the warning bells went off and I looked at other examples. While this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380238/1243762) does not answer your question, the statement

> I suggest instead to have a quick check for validity, and let Prolog work out the insertion points.

lead me to trying a [generate and test](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog9.pdf) methodology for which Prolog is well suited.

First the test part:

No dominoes are valid.

```
domino_test([]).
```

One domino is valid.

```
domino_test([[_,_]]).
```

When ever two dominoes share the same counts (`D_1`) they are valid.
This is recursively valid.

```
domino_test([[_,D_1],[D_1,D_2]|T]) :-
  domino_test([[D_1,D_2]|T]).
```

Next to generate the values. 
This is really just a permutation of the dominoes.

```
?- permutation([[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]],P).
P = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]] ;
P = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]] ;
P = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]] ;
P = [[2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]] ;
P = [[2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]] ;
P = [[2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]] ;
false.
```

Putting the permutation with the test in one predicates gives:

```
list_domino(L,P) :-
  permutation(L,P),
  domino_test(P).
```

---

All of the code

```
domino_test([]).

domino_test([[_,_]]).

domino_test([[_,D_1],[D_1,D_2]|T]) :-
  domino_test([[D_1,D_2]|T]).

list_domino(L,P) :-
  permutation(L,P),
  domino_test(P).
```

Example:

```
?- list_domino([[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]],P).
P = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]] ;
P = [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]] ;
P = [[2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]] ;
false.
```

I suspect your given test case is a simple case and there needs to be a modification to this, but I will let you check it and see.

Comment: thank a lot for your response it solved the
I did just add this :
    list_dominoSorted(X,M,L):-
     append([X],M,P),
     list_domino(P,L).
 to have the same input that i had in the beginning

Comment: @Warmateurrhaa You should post your modified working code as a new section to your question. Others might be interested in what you did.